# Why does a route change trigger .info/connected onDisconnect() to be called?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsx

Why would React Router disconnect the current Firebase AuthUser when checking auth status for another route?

When I switch between Routes (Home, Account, etc.), the onDisconnect() function is called and the status goes from connected to disconnect back to connected within a couple seconds each time.

Routes:

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
        <CustomNavbar />
        <Switch>
            <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
            <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomePage} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} component={AdminPage} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.MANAGER} component={Manager} />
            <Route path={ROUTES.DEFAULT_SETTINGS} component={DefaultSettings} />
            <Redirect to={ROUTES.HOME} />
        </Switch>
        </div>  
    </Router>

    );

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

Auth User Listener:

```
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.onAuthUserListener(
        authUser => {
            this.setState({ authUser });

            var myConnectionsRef = this.props.firebase.db.ref('users/'+authUser.uid+'/connected')

            var connectedRef = this.props.firebase.db.ref('.info/connected');

            connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
              console.log(snap.val())
              if(snap.val() === true){
                  myConnectionsRef.onDisconnect().set(false).then(() => {
                  myConnectionsRef.set(true);
                })
              }
            });    
        });
```

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code here please?

Comment: Im not sure exactly how to show each specific part without putting a confusing amount of code up.. Was hoping to generically find out if this was normal behavior when dealing with react router, or if there should never be "false" disconnects just because a route has changed.

Comment: There's no reason why changing routes should disconnect you, so it'd make sense to see where you're checking the auth status, and your routes.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: If your server-side disconnect handler (`myConnectionsRef.onDisconnect().set(false)`) gets called, the server has lost track of the client. If this happens consistently, it really means that the web socket between client and server is closed when the route changes. You might want to check the network traffic to see if a real page transition is being done. If you don't think so, can you set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like stackblitz.com, so that we can have a look?

Comment: I am currently trying to replicate the problem on stackblitz. In the mean time, I've noticed that it's behaving as if a refresh of the page has happened each time I change routes. Could I be using react router improperly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have solved my issue.

I am using a React Boostrap Navbar component, which includes this tag:

```
<Nav.Link>
```

I was substituting this for the React Router tag:

```
<Link>
```

In order to maintain the styling I had before, simply wrapping a  tag like so:

```
  <Nav.Link>
       <Link to={ROUTES.DEFAULT_SETTINGS}> Settings </Link>
  </Nav.Link>
```

...has fixed the loss of connection during route changes while maintaining style.

Since:

```
<Nav.Link href={ROUTES.DEFAULT_SETTINGS}> Settings </Nav.Link>
```

Does not change routes properly, but instead refreshes the page, is there a more proper practice to display a Bootstrap Link?